# Calculate the determinant of the given square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n \geq 2$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Calculate the determinant of matrix $A = [a_{i,j}]_{i,j} \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$, defined as

\begin{equation}
a_{i,j} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{for}\ i > j, \\
0 & \text{for}\ i = j, \\
-1 & \text{for}\ i < j .\end{cases}
\end{equation}

---

Can anyone provide me with a clue for this question? I've tried to use definition of determinant, but nothing worked out. I've also tried to count determinant for $n = 2$ (my answer is $1$) and $n = 3$ (my answer is $0$).

Comment: Thanks, I've edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stress the dimension of $A$, let us write $A_n$ for $A$. Although it is specified in the question that $n\ge2$, for convenience, we also define $A_1$ as the $1\times1$ zero matrix. When $n\ge3$, we have
$$
A_n=\pmatrix{A_2&-E^T\\ E&A_{n-2}}
$$
where $E$ is a matrix of ones. Note that $EA_2E^T=0$. Therefore, by using blockwise Gaussian elimination or [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement), we get
$$
\det(A_n)
=\det(A_2)\det\left(A_{n-2}-EA_2^{-1}E^T\right)
=\det\left(A_{n-2}+EA_2E^T\right)
=\det(A_{n-2}).
$$
Hence $\det(A_n)$ depends only on the parity of $n$. Since $\det(A_1)=0$ and $\det(A_2)=1$, we conclude that $\det(A_n)=0$ when $n$ is odd and $\det(A_n)=1$ when $n$ is even.

(The proof above works over any commutative ring because $A_2$ is always invertible.)

Comment: It's a simple and good solution, but $n \geq 2$, and I think that we should give example for $\det(A_3)$, not for $\det(A_1)$. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Let $A_n$ be the matrix at hand.

Let $\eta_n$ be the $n\times n$ matrices
with entries $\displaystyle\;\eta_{ij} = \begin{cases}1,&i = j  -1\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\;$.
( ie. $1$ at upper diagonal and $0$ elsewhere)

For $1 \le k < n$, $\eta_n^k$ is a matrix with entries $1$ at $k^{th}$ upper diagonal and $0$ elsewhere.
The upper half of $A_n$ is simply
$$-\eta_n - \eta_n^2 - \cdots - \eta_n^{n-1} = -\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\eta_n^k$$

Furthermore, $\eta_n$ is nilpotent and $\eta_n^k = 0$ for $k \ge n$. The formal power series expansion $\eta_n (I_n - \eta_n)^{-1} = \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \eta_n^k$ terminates and we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \eta_n^k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \eta_n^k = \eta_n(I_n - \eta_n)^{-1}$$
Do the same thing to lower half of $A_n$ with $\bar{\eta}_n = \eta_n^T$ taking the role of $\eta_n$, we obtain
$$A_n = (I_n - \bar{\eta}_n)^{-1}\bar{\eta}_n - \eta_n(I_n - \eta_n)^{-1}$$
This leads to
$$(I_n - \bar{\eta}_n)A_n(I_n - \eta_n) = \bar{\eta}_n(I_n - \eta_n) - (I_n - \bar{\eta}_n)\eta_n = \bar{\eta}_n - \eta_n$$

The rightmost matrix $\bar{\eta}_n - \eta_n$ is a
[tridiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix)
with constant $a = 0$ at diagonal, $b = -1$ at upper diagonal and $c = 1$ at lower diagonal. Let $\Delta_n = \det(\bar{\eta}_n - \eta_n)$. Being determinants of tridiagonal matrices, they satisfy a recurrence relation:

$$\Delta_n = a \Delta_{n-1} - bc \Delta_{n-2}$$
In our case $a = 0$ and $bc = -1$, this leads to
$\Delta_n = \Delta_{n-2}$

Notice $\det(I_n - \eta_n) = \det(I_n - \bar{\eta}_n) = 1$, we find

$$\det(A_n) = \Delta_n = \begin{cases}
\Delta_1 = 0, & n\;\text{odd}\\
\Delta_2 = 1, & n\;\text{even}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Sir, answer is great , though I understood the concept but can you please explain the step in which the series (roughly saying ) of nilpotent matrices is subtracted ,how got you to the result $(I_n - \bar{\eta}_n)^{-1}\bar{\eta}_n - \eta(I_n - \eta_n)^{-1}$

Comment: For $1 \le k < n$, $\eta_n^k$ is a matrix with entries $1$ at $k^{th}$ upper diagonal and $0$ elsewhere. So  $-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\eta_n^k = -(\eta_n + \eta_n^2 + \cdots + \eta_n^{n-1})$ give you upper half of $A$, Since $\eta_n$ is nilpotent, the formal power series expansion of $\eta_n (I_n - \eta_n)^{-1} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \eta_n^k$ terminates at equal to $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\eta_n^k$. Apply same trick to $\bar{\eta}_n$, you get the lower half part of $A$.